# Parity mining in testnet

Tags: solidity, parity

I have recently switched from geth to parity. I want to know how to mine using parity in testnet?
I am synched using `parity --testnet` and I have the web page but how to mine blocks?

Comment: I'm pretty sure ethminer ca be pointed at it.

Comment: so parity itself didn't mine? it needs ethminer or geth to do so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parity doesn't come with bundled miner (not even CPU miner).

You need to install `ethminer` and point it to your Parity instance.

```
# Start Parity and connect to ropsten testnet
$ parity --chain=ropsten

# and in second terminal start ethminer
$ ethminer -F http://localhost:8545
```

Comment: Additionally, `--author` is required for mining, the value to pass in can be the account address.