# Mining for local Parity node

Tags: parity, ethminer, solo-mining

I run a private local Parity node that uses the Ethash engine. How do I use a miner with it?

I tried ethminer like suggested in the wiki (https://wiki.parity.io/Mining), but executing `ethminer -G` responds with "At least one pool URL must be specified". I also tried running `ethminer -F http://localhost:8545` as suggested in [Parity mining in testnet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10561/parity-mining-in-testnet), but it says `The following argument was not expected: -F`.

Here's my mining config section:

`[mining]
engine_signer = "0x00bd138abd70e2f00903268f3db08f2d25677c9e"
author = "0x00bd138abd70e2f00903268f3db08f2d25677c9e"`

And this is my chainspec engine part:

    `"engine": {
        "Ethash": {
            "params": {
                "minimumDifficulty": "0x020000",
                "difficultyBoundDivisor": "0x400",
                "metropolisDifficultyIncrementDivisor": "0xA",
                "blockReward": "0x4563918244F40000",
                "homesteadTransition": "0",
                "difficultyHardforkTransition": "0xC55F7BC23038E38",
                "difficultyHardforkBoundDivisor": "0x800",
                "bombDefuseTransition": "0",
                "eip150Transition": 0,
                "eip160Transition": 0,
                "eip161abcTransition": 0,
                "eip161dTransition": 0,
                "eip170Transition": 0,
                "eip100bTransition":0,
                "eip658Transition":0
            }
        }
    },`

I don't care which miner I use, I just need my transactions to be mined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabled Stratum on my node, then `ethminer -G -P stratum+tcp://127.0.0.1:8008` worked for me.